# Missing styles when adding data from WFD layer from the EA in QGIS 3.16.4

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3

So I have been trying to open data I have previously saved to our PostGIS DB about a couple of years ago. Specificaly these layers relate to the data from the EA WFD River Basin Districts Cycle 1 and 2.

Now when I add these to QGIS the style disappears but the data table is there and visible just not the polygons.

These will however display via GeoServer as a WMS but not WFS which has the same issue.

See image below;
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: can you add details of the URLs you are using to add the layers

Comment: this is the original data from the EA;
https://environment.data.gov.uk/dataset/7846354f-d465-11e4-89d9-f0def148f590

The same also happens with their WFS link

Comment: This does however work in QGIS 3.10.6-A Coruña using exactly the same data from our Postgis DB. but not in 3.10.9-A Coruña